# Python gcm and Django : response is always empty

Tags: android, python, json, django, google-cloud-messaging

I am using python gcm for Django.response=json.dumps(gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids,data=data)).response is always NULL. But message is sent

Their documentation suggested:

```
response=json.dumps(gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids,data=data))
```

Well! Message is received to mobile successfully. But the problem is response value is always empty.

My code:

```
def sendNotification(request):
        gcm = GCM('AIzXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
        reg_ids=[]
        devices=Devices.objects.all()

        for device in devices:
            reg_ids.append(device.gcm_reg_id)
        data = {'sender': "someone",'message':"Cool!",}
        response=json.dumps(gcm.json_request(registration_ids=reg_ids,data=data))
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Empty as in blank or empty as in {} ? which response is it the HttpResponse or the response from gcm.json_request ?

Comment: +e4c5 empty as {} The response variable from gcm.json_request.

Comment: Smells like a bug in python gcm. Will you trying sending a message with a direct HTTP call? my answer here explains how to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33185108/267540   it's actually really easy.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me !!:)